# XTDE0160 : XSLT 1.0 compatibility mode is not available in this configuration in buil-in template rule for /invoice:request in the unnamed mode

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm always with the same problem. I've allready created a question : Namespace prefix xsl on value-of is not defined. thanks to Michael for his answers. I saw all similar questions, but I found nothing to help me. I test my code with saxon9he and I try to group it with muenchian method.
XML file :

```
<invoice:request xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:invoice="http://www.xmlData.ch/xmlInvoice/XSD" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/invoice MDInvoiceRequest_400.xsd" role="production">

    <invoice:invoice invoice_id="22">
      <invoice:vat>0.00</invoice:vat>
      <invoice:record_tarmed>Rapport médical sur formulaire assurance-maladie</invoice:record_tarmed>
  </invoice:invoice>
    <invoice:invoice invoice_id="23">
      <invoice:vat>5.00</invoice:vat>
      <invoice:record_tarmed>Salle d'examen et de traitement, chirurgie et chirurgie pédiatrique</invoice:record_tarmed>
   </invoice:invoice> 
</invoice:request>
```

XSLT file :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:invoice="http://www.xmlData.ch/xmlInvoice/XSD"
  exclude-result-prefixes="invoice">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="factures-par-TVA" match="invoice:invoice" use="invoice:vat"/>
  <xsl:template match="invoice:request">
    <Documents>
       <xsl:for-each select="invoice:invoice[count(. | key('factures-par-TVA', invoice:vat)[1]) = 1]">
          <xsl:sort select="invoice:vat" />
          <Document>
            <xsl:copy-of select="invoice:vat" />
            <xsl:for-each select="key('factures-par-TVA',invoice:vat)">
               <xsl:sort select="invoice:invoice/@invoice_id"/>
               <xsl:copy-of select="invoice:record_tarmed"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Document>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Documents>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is the same : error XTDE0160. If I remove 'invoice:' for 'request', the temp.html file contains the text of the 4 nodes and I get this warning SXXP0005 : the source document is in namespace http://www.xmlData.ch/xmlInvoice/XSD, but all the template rules match elements in no namespace.

I tried the mode attribute of xsl:template but it does'nt work.

what can I do ?

thanks for your help

Comment: If you are using Saxon 9.8 HE then make sure your stylesheet has `version="3.0"` or `version="2.0"`, Saxon 9.8 is an XSLT 3.0 processor and HE has dropped support for `version="1.0"` backwards compatibility.

Comment: See also http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/conformance/xslt30.html saying `Saxon-HE will reject stylesheets that specify version="1.0"` and https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#err-XTDE0160.

Comment: So if your target system is an XSLT 1.0 processor I wouldn't recommend using Saxon 9.8 HE to test your stylesheets.

Answer (score 10):

As Martin points out in his comments (which should really have been an answer) the message means that Saxon9-HE no longer offers XPath 1.0 compatibility mode, so it won't run a stylesheet labelled with version="1.0". The last open source Saxon release to offer this feature is Saxon 9.7, which of course is still available.

Presumably there is some reason you don't want to move forward to XSLT 2.0 or 3.0: the `xsl:for-each-group` instruction makes this kind of code so much simpler.

**UPDATE** (30 Jan 2018): In response to popular demand, we have reverted this change. Later maintenance releases of Saxon-HE from 9.8.0.7 have reinstated the ability to run XSLT 1.0 stylesheets in backwards-compatibility mode.

Comment: Can you please take a look into the documentation of Saxon-HE 10 at saxon.sourceforge.net/#F10HE and make an update about this revert. Currently the official documentation says -> "Not included in the Home Edition are: schema processing and schema aware XSLT and XQuery; support for XPath 1.0 (and XSLT 1.0) backwards compatibility mode,".

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. We don't maintain documentation on the SourceForge site any more, but I'll see what we can do.